# Should I change my hard disk or not?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-8, kali-linux

I am unable to find the cause of problem in my pc.
Whole problem is that no operating system is working properly on my pc.
It came with windows 7. It worked fine for almost 7-8 months but now each operating system continues failing. I have tried all os window 7, 8,10 . Whenever I install new os it works well for almost a day then it slows down and almost in 3-4 days the error always showed was bad system, kernel problem, crashes and corrupted registries. Finally I changed to Linux and it worked fine for a month some times some errors occurred but they were fixed by using fsck command. But now my hard disk is totally dead. I am thinking to change the hard disk but I am not sure that the problem is with the hard disk because I have cleared my hard disk completely many times. So do you have any answers that is my hard disk only problem or there is any other problem. I am currently using kali live but it is also slowing down and some crashes too. Can you help me in this issue?

Comment: I would try to check the RAM's as well with Memtest86 but if your harddrive is dead, just buy another one. Right now, it's hard to tell what's going on, what did you try to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is Memtest86 possible in kali live. So that I can be assured that my RAM is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It would *appear* that your disk is failing. Kali-live if run from external media (`CD/DV/Flash drive`) should *not* slow down. *unless* you have given it access to your (possibly failing) hard drive. If you *haven't* given access to kali to the hard drive, and there isn't already a `swap` slice on the drive from an earlier *Linux* install. Then your problem may be the drive ports (assuming kali is run from `CD/DVD`).

But in the end. I'm fairly sure that given your indication of having *previously* installed Linux to the hard drive. That Kali found, and is making use of the left over `swap` slice from the earlier Linux install. Thus slowing down the system, and causing the crashes.

If it were me. I'd invest in a new hard drive.

Lastly; If you go into your `BIOS` setup, and enable [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T), and save the settings. You're computer should *fail* to allow you to continue to boot, if the drive reports problems (that it's failing to correct errors it encounters). Or it (the BIOS`) may pause with a report that the disk says it is encountering unrecoverable errors.

This would be a **conclusive** report that your drive is near death.

Comment: Actually I have cleaned my hard disk completely before it's failure . But my worry is that in case the hard disk is not my only problem ? Kali live isn't crashing but it is slowing down day by day. I am facing problems like slow response of appications and their crashes in kali live else their is no problem. Even I am sure to change my hard disk but I want to know the cause of the problems I have been facing from almost two months. When I had my linux installed there were no crashes the only problem was corrupted registeries which I used to fix using fsck command.Only windows had crashes.

Comment: @Xavier if there are only problems when any of the OSs *touch* the hard drive. I'd bet the hard drive is failing. You can test if the hard drive is being used while in a *NIX system (Linux/*BSD) using `df -h`, and looking for the hard drive device name. I've updated my answer with additional information that should provide you with a definitive answer as to your drives *present* condition.

Comment: I am not currently using the hard drive but the kali live also got some problems. Yesterday When I was using vim for writing some code suddenly black screen appeared with some errors like : SQUASHFS error : Unable to read directory block [some hex code ..] and print_req_error : I/O error , dev loop0 , sector 96674   What do these error mean?